# How add a complete Click MouseGesture to a ListBoxItem in XAML

Tags: wpf, vb.net, command, gesture, inputbinding

I have a `ListBoxItem` with a `LeftClick` Gesture:

```
<ListBoxItem x:Name="ListViewItemMenu" Content="{Binding Path=Header}" Padding="37 14" FontSize="15" Foreground="White">
    <ListBoxItem.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="ApplicationCommands.New" />
    </ListBoxItem.InputBindings>
</ListBoxItem>
```

But actually it's not a real Click, it's simply a `MouseLeftButtonDown` Gesture. The `Command` is executed regardless of whether the button is raised or not after pressed.

I would like to have a complete Click with the `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` Gestures in the `ListBoxItem`. There is anyway to do that? Much appreciated.

Also I can't find a way to add a `Command` to an `Expander`. The method shown above to the `ListBoxItem` doesn't work. Any magic here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28174199/5086631) you can inherit from [`MouseGesture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.mousegesture) to create custom gestures. There is even a full example with implementation.

An alternative is to use an [`System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/design-tools/expression-studio-4/ff726541(v%3Dexpression.40)) as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21942689/5086631), which would let you turn the `MouseLeftButtonUp` or `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp` event into a command trigger.